# Why use the word "chasm" instead of just "gap" or "hole"

Tags: word-choice

With every example sentence I've read so far, I can't see why we can't replace *chasm* with *gap*. Is there any other meaning of the word?

Comment: Can you give some examples of what you've read?

Comment: 'The Grand Canyon is an awesome sight, an astounding, mesmerising, even terrifying hole.'

Comment: Mind the chasm, too.

Comment: Chasm emphasises the size of the space. You can have a tiny gap or a tiny hole, but you can't have a tiny little chasm :)

Comment: Because it sounds deep.

Answer (score 4):

Well they do have similar meanings.

> chasm
> A deep fissure in the earth, rock, or another surface.
> -- [Google Dictionary](http://www.google.com/search?q=define%20chasm)
>
> gap
> A break or hole in an object or between two objects.
> -- [Google Dictionary](http://www.google.com/search?q=define%20gap)

So yes, very similar. However, one of the (amazing) things about English is that there are many words that mean the same thing. A chasm is a much better word to describe a large, deep gap in the earth's surface, or an ice plane. Just reading gap, gap, gap gets boring.

So sure, you could change chasm for gap, but why would you? English isn't there to be simple, it's there to be able to describe one things is masses of detail.

Comment: In summation: _chasm_ has a more specific and rich meaning than _gap_ or _hole._

Comment: @DetachedLaconian yes, and while you *could* say “There’s a big hole in the ice”, people would not imagine a chasm, they would probably imagine a circular-ish hole, leading to water below (https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ice+fishing+hole).

Answer (score 0):

A "chasm" is a very great gap.  If I read "John jumped across the gap" then I would not necessarily picture John taking a huge leap (unless the gap had been previously described as being quite large and deep).  But if I read "John jumped across the chasm" then I would picture John's effortful leap.

A gap could be quite shallow, too, but nobody is going to visualize a shallow or narrow chasm.  A chasm is normally perceived as wide and deep and something not easily negotiated, if at all.  The Grand Canyon in Arizona is a chasm.  The space between two platforms at Paddington Station in London is a gap.

See what I mean?

Answer (score -4):

In addition to what's said in the previous response, you want to use "chasm" when there are connotations of evil, or insurmountable difference. Check what these dictionaries say:

http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=chasm&allowed_in_frame=0

http://www.ozdic.com/collocation-dictionary/chasm

Comment: Where dod you get the notion of evil from other than colocation with other imaginative prose?

Comment: The word relates to "chaos" via its greek root. This is not to say it takes on the connotation every time it's used, rather, that in my opinion you'd be better off with chasm instead of gap when you want to denote that.

Comment: I think you are making an association that doesn't exist with the divergence of meaning over time. The similar meanings of the early Greek *khaos* and *khasma* don't reflect the evolution of chaos as the disordered void that was before creation, which eventually came to mean orderless confusion. And none of that hints at evil.

Comment: But we can safely assume that chasm retains a close association with the original khasma and thus with khaos, can´t we ? Your correction about the divergence is noted.

In respect to the connotation of evil, again, it's clear that it's not part of the dictionary definition, but that this word collocates with this notion more often than the more generic "gap" seems to be the case. You have it in "Kubla Khan", by Coleridge. To me it looks that its mere modern definition brings about this notion easily. Thanks for your comment, though, it made me look deeper into it.

Comment: So probably the notion of evil is better explained by what the modern definition can point at, instead of the relationship between chasm and chaos. My apologies if my reasoning seemed fuzzy or my use of English was incorrect.

Comment: 'This is not to say it takes on the connotation every time it's used' assumes a sense of 'connotation' different from this: 'Connotation refers to the emotional implications and associations that a word may carry.' [grammar.about]  / 'b. The set of associations implied by a word in addition to its literal meaning.' [AHD]. So a word _has_ connotations, according to these definitions, whether Aloysius and Charlotte pick up on all the associations or not.